# GridView Column filtering

Tags: asp.net, filter, currency, money-format

I have a GridView control set up, populated from a database through the BL, and one of the fields contains currency amounts. Right now it is displaying in the format of 0000.0000, and I need to bring it to a currency format that adds $ + dataNumber down to hundredths.

I have looked for filters, but so far I haven't seen a direct and simple answer. Could using a regular expression to filter work? :/

It is my first attempt to do so. Any answers are appreciated, but please provide site documentation for me to reference while attempting to implement your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridView.BoundColumn` type provides the [**`DataFormatString`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.dataformatstring.aspx) property you can use to specify the display format.  You can use the `C` format to display in currency format.

```
<Columns>
    ...
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyFieldName" DataFormatString="C" />
    ...
</Columns>
```

Comment: Thank you. My searches were including the word filter instead of format. I understand my mistake and appreciate you time to answer.